# query for nested collection document element in mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

The following is the movies collection document:

```
{
    "_id" : "1312201612915", 
    "_class" : "general", 
    "movie" : "twilight", 
    "theatre" : DBRef("theatres", "IX")
}
```

following is the theatres collection document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "IX",  
    "name" : "Inox", 
    "state" : DBRef("states", "KR")
}
```

following is the states collection document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "KR", 
    "name" : "kerala"
}
```

here i want the name from states collection. How to get it using mongo query in java spring?

Comment: you can use `$lookup` in `aggregate` query to get state name from movie collection

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to get theatres and movies from by state name?

Comment: @AbzalKalimbetov yes you understood correctly. Can you help me with some java code??

Comment: @ShaishabRoy ...thank you . Can you please help me with java code??

Comment: Can you pls add he code that you have tried ? We'll know where you are stuck and can help you from there

Comment: this is not helping, but i'm still telling, it is not a good idea to build relations with mongodb, it is not designed for that. consider just embedded the data in the movie collection.

Comment: You have an [xy-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) - the question you should ask yourself is, why do you use a relation model in a non-relational database which obviously does not help you with your queries. Try to get a basic grip on mongo db design instead. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/data-modeling-introduction/